# Is it possible to ensure iisnode respects NODE_PATH in Azure?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service, iisnode, azure-app-service-envrmnt

It is not uncommon to want to be able to have non-relative imports, for example, for configuration, etc...

In the world of running a node executable on your own (development env, any cloud provider... things like that) you can simply set an env var and have it respected by the node runtime.

Imagine a project structure like so:
dist
|--foo
    |--bar
        |--baz
            app.js
|--config

in app.js with NODE_PATH=dist, I can simply require('config') and have what I need.

Within Azure App Services, it appears to ignore NODE_PATH from Application Settings. Is something missing or is this not possible?

Comment: Hi @James Yeoh, any update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Azure App Services, you can set the `NODE_PATH` environment variable in the Azure portal with the following steps.

1, Create the `D:\home\site\my_node_modules\config` directory and put the index.js file in where. In this case, I just export the "name" variable.

```
// D:\home\site\my_node_modules\config\index.js
var name = "foobar";
// export it
exports.name = name;
```

2, Navigate to your App Service in the [Azure portal](https://ms.portal.azure.com), click on **Application settings** in the **SETTING** menu and then set the `NODE_PATH` variable as below:

[image]

3, In the `app.js` file, you can simply `require('config')` like this:

```
var http = require('http')
var config = require('config')

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.end(config.name)
}).listen(process.env.PORT || 3000)
```

4, At last, it works fine.

[image]

Comment: My pleasure. Please mark it as answer if you feel so.. :)